# how to open URL scheme (mailto, tel) on q-item click?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I wish to make a `<q-list>` of contacts with their telephone numbers, emails and addresses and I'm trying to make the `<q-item>`s clickable so that when the user clicks on any of the q-items, the phone dialer/mail-client/naviation app will fire up.

From what I gather `<q-item>` only supports @click but I can't think of a way other than `openURL` to pass the URL scheme (eg "tel:55512345"). The documentation however [advises against it](https://quasar.dev/quasar-utils/other-utils). 
What is good way of doing it?

```
    <q-item clickable>
      <q-item-section avatar>
        <q-icon name="mail" />
      </q-item-section>
      <q-item-section>
        <q-item-label>mail@mail.com</q-item-label>
         <q-item-label caption>email</q-item-label>
       </q-item-section>
    </q-item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the docs advises to use an `a`(nchor) element for it, why not do so by using the `tag` prop and the native `href` for the URL scheme:

```html
<q-item 
  tag="a"
  href="tel:55512345"
  clickable>
  <q-item-section avatar>
    <q-icon name="mail" />
  </q-item-section>
  <q-item-section>
    <q-item-label>mail@mail.com</q-item-label>
    <q-item-label caption>email</q-item-label>
  </q-item-section>
</q-item>
```

Comment: thank you! that solved the problem! I'm still fumbling my way around vue.js and quasar!